# Find the corresponding value in a separate table depending on another table in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I am trying to find the value in one table (Table 2), based on the location of a "Yes" in another table (Table 1). See below:

Table 1

```
Header1  Unique1  Unique2  Unique3
Row1        Yes
Row2                 Yes
Row3                          Yes
```

Table 2

```
Header1  Unique1  Unique2  Unique3
Row1        XXX
Row2                 YYY
Row3                          ZZZ
```

On another sheet, I have a column with "Unique1" or "Unique2" as follows and am trying to get the column that is labeled "Lookup":

```
Column1  Lookup
Unique1     XXX
Unique1     XXX
Unique3     ZZZ
Unique2     YYY
```

Comment: try =Match("Yes",B:B,0) which you can drag right to get the row you want in Table 1 (and so in Table 2). Then use =INDEX(B for start row of Table 2:B for End Row, the value from the match).

Comment: Oh, but you cannot assume column names are sequential, so you also need =Match("Unique1",1:1). and to supply that as the third parameter to index

Comment: Ah got it - do some of the computing on the back-end instead of pulling everything through in 1 formula. Got it working!

Answer (score 0):

I am glad you got it working. I actually did manage to cram it into one formula.`=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$5:$D$8,MATCH("Yes",INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&CHAR(CODE("A")+MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$1:$1,0)-1)&":"&CHAR(CODE("A")+MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$1:$1,0)-1)),0),MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$1:$1,0))`
The way that works is it goes into your table 2 and picks out a row and a column. The column is whichever holds the name. The row gets constructed by looking for yes in the appropriate column. To name that column with a letter and not a number, I needed to convert with the whole CHAR CODE thing.